# Coldest Temperature Visible to the Naked Eye

Tags: thermal-radiation, vision

If I take a black body radiation emitter, how hot does it have to be before it becomes visible to the naked eye? Placing an upper limit is trivial, just look up the [surface temperature of red dwarf stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_dwarf) (about 2500 K). But at what temeprature does the [Wien tail approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Approximations) produce enough light to meet the surface brightness sensitivity limits of the naked eye? So I'm not as interested in the case where the emitting surface is much smaller than can be resolved, because that answer will depend sensitively on the surface area of the emitter.

Comment: Eons ago, while doing rapid heating of samples with quartz lamps, I got pretty good at estimating sample temperature from the color. Somewhere around 450C you could see a very dull dim red glow, by 500C it was quite clearly red, and 550C it was hard to look at. Your eyes, hopefully, are better than mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iron is a reasonably good approximation to a black body emitter, and Wikipedia helpfully give [a table of appearance as a function of temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_heat#Chapman). The black body radiation is first visible at around 450ºC. I note this matches Jon's description of the appearance of heated quartz.